# Webkit2png not working with --ignore-ssl-check

Tags: python, http, security

I'm using webkit2png to take a screenshot of this website: http://www.ukmt-resources.org.uk/JMC16.html

I received a security error, to which I found the answer was to put --ignore-ssl-check into the code. This only works for some websites, however.
I am using the following code in my Mac terminal:

webkit2png --ignore-ssl-check -D ~/Desktop http://www.ukmt-resources.org.uk/JMC16.html

Why is it still not granting me permission? I get this instead:

"App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
 ... something went wrong: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."

Comment: Did you try https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6205 "App Transport Security and local networking" or https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544 "Application Transport Security ?".  Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http?

Comment: Those seem to focus on apps and info.plist files. I am not using any app, I simply want to gain access to a site from my Mac's terminal so that the webkit2png can do its job.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210588/how-does-one-configure-a-temporary-exception-to-ats-on-el-capitan-and-fix-webkit suggests hacking webkit2png to insert the disabling of ATS in https://github.com/bendalton/webkit2png/commit/9a96ac8977c386a84edb674ca1518e90452cee88

Answer (score 0):

Answer to an old question:

I could work around the error "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." by installing my self-signed certificate locally.

I followed this guide: https://tosbourn.com/getting-os-x-to-trust-self-signed-ssl-certificates/

> 1. Locate where your certificate file is. It is likely to be somewhere near your web server configurations.
> 2. Open up Keychain Access. You can get to it from Application/Utilities/Keychain Access.app.
> 3. Drag your certificate into Keychain Access.
> 4. Go into the Certificates section and locate the certificate you just added
> 5. Double click on it, enter the trust section and under “When using this certificate” select “Always Trust”

In my case I installed the SSL certificate of my local apache, as defined in the virtual host:

```
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
```